# Data Type Error when added Input Mask on Date Time Field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have a date/time field called MyDate. Originally, its format is mm/dd/yyyy and there is no input mask. The Date Picker is also set. I then added input mask using Short date , changed the default input maks to (99-99-0000;;_) and change the format to mm-dd-yyyy. However, when i switch to DataSheet view , all my dates are changed from mm/dd/yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy (which is the correct behaviour right? ) and when I tried to enter a new date or modify existing date, it says "The value you entered does not match Date/Time data type in this column". Plus, the DatePicker is missing. How can I resolve this. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date time picker is not available if an input mask is applied to a field: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-and-customize-date-and-time-formats-HA010078108.aspx#_Toc272229486

Regarding the error, have you considered using your regional settings in the control panel, which sets the defaukt date display for all (most?) applications?

Dates in Access are stored as numbers, so you can format them however you like, but I suspect the input mask may need to match the regional settings, although I am not certain.